# Adamant Iframe width

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am developing a webpage which carries an iframe inside a div. I cannot make the iframe strech across full width of its parent div even after making width 100% in CSS.

I am doing something wrong. Please have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/JTHN8/

This is my iframe CSS:

```
position:relative;
margin-left:0%
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

What I want is iframe should have about 80% of width of its parent div.

Comment: You also have `iframe#mainiframe {width:300;}` in your fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit how stupid I was in omitting that semicolon after margin-left!
Fixed CSS:

```
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
```

A thing to learn though; If you skip a semicolon in CSS, only the next line will be skipped. Lines beyond that still work.